# How to play a gif only on onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code below which loads **gif animation** from an **array character**, and loads it to **class board** inside the `image src`.

`I want to play the gif animation`**only when i click on that gif displayed**`.`

it is now playing the gif as soon as it loads the gif

`How to change my code to display the gif from array as it is doing now but play the gif only when i click on it?`

```js
number = 0;
var animations = ['https://image.ibb.co/epha5A/giphy.gif',
  'https://image.ibb.co/epha5A/giphy.gif',
  'https://image.ibb.co/epha5A/giphy.gif'
];

function character() {

  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = animations[number];

  console.log(number);
  number++;


}
```

```css
.board {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.3vh;
  left: 10vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.board img {
  width: 35.3vw;
  height: 45.5vh;
  border-radius: 15%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="character();">

  <div class="board">
    <img src="" id="hiddenimageid" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can keep an image for each gif  and on click change the image src to gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go :

```js
number = 0;
var animations = ['https://image.ibb.co/epha5A/giphy.gif',
  'https://image.ibb.co/epha5A/giphy.gif',
  'https://image.ibb.co/epha5A/giphy.gif'
];


 var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = animations[number];
},1)


function character() {
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = animations[number];

  console.log(number);
  number++;


}
```

```css
.board {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.3vh;
  left: 10vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.board img {
  width: 35.3vw;
  height: 45.5vh;
  border-radius: 15%;
}
```

```html
<body onclick="character();">

  <div class="board">
    <img src="" id="hiddenimageid" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Using this solution you won't have to convert the image to a png or jpeg. You can simply use your code as it is. I hope this helps you

Answer (score 3):

I convert yout `gif` to `png` using this site:https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png

Then set `onclick` to img that change the `src` to your `gif`

Now you can do it to other `gif`

```js
number = 0;
var animations = ['https://image.ibb.co/epha5A/giphy.gif',
  'https://image.ibb.co/epha5A/giphy.gif',
  'https://image.ibb.co/epha5A/giphy.gif'
];


function character() {

  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = animations[number];

}
```

```css
.board {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.3vh;
  left: 10vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.board img {
  width: 35.3vw;
  height: 45.5vh;
  border-radius: 15%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="board">
    <img src=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqbOp.png" id="hiddenimageid" onclick="character();"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @%d7%9c%d7%91%d7%a0%d7%99-%d7%9e%d7%9c%d7%9b%d7%94  i need to click on that image to play it. thanks in advance

Comment: @%d7%9c%d7%91%d7%a0%d7%99-%d7%9e%d7%9c%d7%9b%d7%94 thanks for support

Comment: happy to help :)